# UPDATE mysql for multiple users

Tags: php, mysql

i have a form that updates the score between 2 teams.
and i want to update score for people who hit the exact score.
i want to check if someone actually did and then add points.
if i do it for 1 person its working but i want to check and add for multiple users

i tried to fix it but i cant find any answer ..

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $result = mysql_query("UPDATE `match`  SET 
      `match`.`home_goal`  = '".$_POST['home_goal']."', 
      `match`.`away_goal`  = '".$_POST['away_goal']."'
      WHERE `match`.`id`  = '".$_POST['gameid']."'");

    $result2 = mysql_query(
                 "SELECT * FROM `match_guess` WHERE 
                 `match_guess`.`match_id` = '".$_POST['gameid']."'");
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
         if($_POST['home_goal'] == $row2['home_goals'] && 
            $_POST['away_goal'] == $row2['away_goals']) {

             $result3 = mysql_query("UPDATE `members`  SET 
             `members`.`acc`  = `members`.`acc` + 1, 
             `members`.`points`  = `members`.`points` + 5
             WHERE `members`.`id`  = '".$row2['user_id']."'");  
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to check if you `if` statement returns `TRUE` and if your `UPDATE` query works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not executing $result3 in the while loop, so it is being overwritten. $result3 (or rather, $sql3) should be defined outside the loop and appended inside the loop and executed after the loop

```
$sql3 = "UPDATE `members` 
    SET `members`.`acc`  = `members`.`acc` + 1, 
        `members`.`points`  = `members`.`points` + 5 
    WHERE `members`.`id`  = '0'";

while(...) {
    if(...){
        $sql3 .= " OR `members`.`id` = '".$row2['user_id']."'";
    }
}

$result3 = mysql_query($sql3);
```